# Problem with a regex to extract informations of a filename

Tags: regex

I have to extract informations of filenames.

- There is a possible name which can contains a-z , 0-9 , - , _
- There is a possible separator which can be _ , . , / , \ , * , # or a space
- There is always a number before the extension
- There is always an extension

For now, here is where I am

```
^((?<name>[a-z0-9-_]+)(?<separator>[_\.#\/\\*\- ])){0,1}(?<number>\d+)\.(?<extension>[a-z]{3})$
```

I have to match all of theses:

```
tot0_tutu_00001.tif
tot0.0001.tif
tot0#00001.tif
tot0/0001.tif
tot0\00001.tif
tot0*0001.tif
00001.tif
tot0-tutu_0001.tif
tot0-tutu-00001.tif
tot0-tutu 000001.tif
tot0-tutu000001.tif
```

That regex is working for all cases axcept the last one

```
tot0-tutu000001.tif
```

I cannot figure how to solve this

Here is a sandbox
https://regex101.com/r/wZP6RI/1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The filenames do not start with a separator, so you could make the whole name part optional. If it is present, make sure it starts with a-z0-9 and optionally match the separator.

For the digits part, you can use a negative lookbehind to start matching digits where there is no digit directly before it.

```
^(?<name>(?:[a-z0-9]+(?:[-_][a-z0-9]+)*(?<separator>[_\.#\/\\*\- ]?))?)(?<!\d)(?<number>\d+)\.(?<extension>[a-z]{3})$
```

- `^` Start of string
- `(?<name>` Named group *name*

  - `(?:` Non capture group

    - `[a-z0-9]+` Match 1+ occurrences of a range a-z or 0-9
    - `(?:[-_][a-z0-9]+)*` Optionally repeat the previous with either `-` or `_` prepended
    - `(?<separator>` Named group *separator*

      - `[_\.#\/\\*\- ]?` Optionally match any of the listed chars
    - `)` Close group separator
  - `)?` Close non capture group and make it optional
- `)` Close group *name*
- `(?<!\d)(?<number>\d+)` Named group *number* match 1+ digits asserting no digit directly to the right
- `\.(?<extension>[a-z]{3})` Match `.` and named group *extension* matching 3 times a char in range a-z
- `$` End of string

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/CYOcv4/1)

Answer (score 0):

According to the criteria you stated, it feels like it could be simplified:

```
^[a-z0-9_-]*[_.\/\\*# ]?\d+\.[a-z]{3}$
```

See https://regex101.com/r/z5eRwM/1.

Feel free to regroup as you need.

Side note, careful with `-` in char classes, it needs to be either at the very beginning or at the very end to be considered as the `-` char (and not the range separator as in `[a-z]`):

- `[-az]`: matches `-`, `a` and `z`
- `[a-z]`: matches chars between `a` and `z` (`-` excluded)
- `[az-]`: matches `a`, `z` and `-`